# In C, how to detect boundary write error in free() function implementation?

Tags: c

A boundary error is when a program reads or writes memory beyond the actual dimensions of an allocated memory block. An example boundary write error is to write the 11th entry in an array of size 10

I have a test that must detect boundary write error in `my_free()` function implementation

```
 int main()
 {   
   const char* string1 = "Hello, this is a string! I exist to demonstrate a common error.";
   char* copy_of_string1 = (char*) my_malloc(strlen(string1));

  // Whoops! Forgot to allocate space for the '\0' that ends the string.
   strcpy(copy_of_string1, string1); // == boundary write error
   my_free(copy_of_string1);

   return 0;
 }
```

How to catch the case where the user writes one or more zero bytes directly after the allocated block ?

Comment: Write `0xDEADBEEF` after the block in `my_malloc()`, and read it back in `my_free()`?

Comment: @TavianBarnes nice idea... But it could fail if the written data after the block matches the `0xDEADBEEF`.

Comment: It's the best way, even Microsoft does it: http://www.nobugs.org/developer/win32/debug_crt_heap.html
Additionally, if you pick a large "random" number, the odds of an exact match are less than one in four billion.  Pretty good odds.

Comment: Use valgrind. This is one of many errors it can easily detect.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart I was thinking of that, it would be good to check their source code to see how they achieve that.

Comment: I emulate my heap used array:

 static char  heap[Heap_Capacity];

and when I write '\0' directly after the allocated block I cannot detect that this is 0 or '\0'. Because after the initialization I have array with zeros

Comment: @iharob I suspect it's quite complicated.  From the man page: *"It consists of a core, which provides a synthetic CPU in software..."*

Comment: @AnatolyPetrushenko `'\0'` is identical to `(char)0`.

Comment: @AnatolyPetrushenko; Well it is difficult to implement the boundary write error detection in function `my_free()`, but you can achieve the same easily by writing your own `strcpy` function.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Yes, this is a problem. I can see difference with them

Comment: @AnatolyPetrushenko In what way? I assure you, `'\0'` is a `char` literal, with value 0.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart All chunks of my heap memory have zero value after the initialization. So when I write '\0'  directly after the allocated block, for example into the chunk A, *A will not change

Comment: I guess, the only fully proof way (apart from the Valgrind approach) is to allocate the space at the end of a memory page and handle the resulting fault (maybe allocate 2 adjacent pages; the second being unwritable?). That way when you overrun your buffer you can handle the resulting bus error and write something for my_free to read.

Maybe not a viable alternative to the `0xDEADBEEF`, but figured it should be noted.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart : wrong. '\0' is an **integer** literal (represented as a character) Try: `printf("%zu\n", sizeof '\0' );` to verify.

Comment: @wildplasser Good point, I always forget that oddity of C. The fact that it's value is 0 still stands.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The common practice is to allocate some more memory than required and put a marker at the end (in the overallocated memory). When freeing, you will check that the marker has not been overwritten.

For myself I've created a custom version of `malloc()` which puts a marker both at the beginning and at the end of a block:

```
      +--------+
      |  size  |
      |BEEFF00D|
  p-> |  ...   |
      |DEADC0DA|
      +--------+
```

and will return `p` rather than the really allocated block.

When I `free()` the block I check that right before the pointer there is the value `0xBEEFF00D` and if not, the pointer to be freed is not valid.  Then, if it's valid, I check the end of the block (of which I've stored the size) and see if the marker `0xDEADC0DA` is there, if not there has been an out of boundary error.

If everything is fine, before freeing up the (real) block I replace the initial marker `0xBEEFF00D` with the marker `0xDEFACED` so to catch double `free()` errors.

I've set everything up so that I can include an header and compile with the symbol `MEMCHECK` to make so that every `free()`, `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `realloc()` and `strdup()` will be replaced by my checking version.  When I'm sure everything is fine, I'll recompile without `MEMCHECK` defined.  This might be too overkill for you, but if you interested you can find my code here: https://github.com/rdentato/memchk with some explanation here: https://dev.to/rdentato/c-memories-33kc (look at the end of the article).

Comment: Windows has a built-in Debug Heap which does all this automatically.  When you execute a program with Visual Studio, it uses this debug heap automatically.  Just an interesting note.

Comment: +1 Others have pointed out that this approach can't detect *every* write outside of the allocated block. But it's a reasonable approach. It is not practical to detect all writes outside of this area.

Comment: Link is now broken

Comment: I've fixed the link and added the link to a DEV.to article I wrote about this. Hope it helps.